# Kibana subtract metric from a number

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

is it possible to subtract a number that metric outputs from predefined number in Kibana?

Eg I have a number that one of the metric produces (num of events), and I would need a way to subtract predefined number out of that metric (manual input), how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [formulas in lens](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/lens.html#lens-formulas) to subtract numbers from metric outputs.